# How to turn off animations in headless google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, automated-tests, capybara, material-design

When running automated tests with google chrome in headless mode (driving them with capybara), I would like to turn off animations. 
Is this possible?

An example of animations are tabs that have a transistion between pages such as this [one](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs).

Thanks

Comment: How to turn off animations is completely dependent on the library you're using for the animations

Comment: Hi Thomas, 
Agreed. I will update the tag list to reflect that I am using angular material design.

Answer (score 2):

With angular you should be able to include the NoopAnimationsModule to disable most animations - https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-2-animations